# two expressions in one expression builder in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, expressionbuilder

Can we use two expressions in expression builder in data factory?

For example:

If I have a string column and I would like to to have two expression in expression builder. the two conditions are: if a value is empty then return space '' or if a value is not integer then return the column name.

```
iifNull(column1,'Unknown') OR iif(!isInteger(column1),'column1',toString(null()))
```

Answer (score 0):

These are effectively the same ... does it help?

iifNull(column1,'Unknown',column1)

iif(isNull(),'Unknown',column1)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#iifnull

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#iif

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#isnull

Comment: Haha, you meant "OR" inside your expression, not should you use 1 or the other, lol. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

> or( : boolean,  : boolean) => boolean
>
> Logical OR operator. Same as ||.
>
> or(true, false) -> true
>
> true || false -> true

No. If you want to use `or()` function in expression builder, the parameter must be boolean value. Your expression returns string value, so it can't work. You need to do this in two expression builder.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#or

Comment: how the two expression builder will work?

Comment: @user2841795 Which of the two `iif()` has higher priority ?  If your colomn1's value is 'abc', which is your expected result, 'Unknown' or 'column1'?